# Unity 2D rhythm game prefab object spawn slower after build

Tags: unity-game-engine

im totally newbie in unity, my brother helped me in coding and now we stuck on a problem. we're making a 2D mobile (android) rhythm game based on our folk songs. the problem is like in the title.

game demo: [https://youtu.be/UJl461f8QZc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJl461f8QZc)

its just miliseconds late but its so uncomfortable, we only adjust the time just like the songs original beats per minute.

this is the code we write to define the time so we can write the time (ms) in the editor

```
   /* void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(0 , -speed * Time.deltaTime , 0);
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }*/

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = -transform.up * speed * 45f * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

as you can see, the fixedDeltaTime doesn't work either

and this is the code to spawn the tiles :

```
    public void Muncul()
    {
        int RG = Random.Range(0 , graphics.Length);
        int SD = Random.Range(0 , spawner.Count);

        GameObject t = Instantiate(tiles , spawner[SD].position , spawner[SD].rotation);

        t.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = graphics[RG];
    }
```

and to create how many tiles to spawn, we use code to record the song we played and then it detects the beats in song to spawn the tile per beat.

i appreciate any help, and sorry for my bad english

Comment: A `velocity` already **is** a value per second and should not be multiplied by `Time.deltaTime` or `Time.fixedDeltaTime` .. and how is `Muncul` called?

Comment: @derHugo Ah i see. muncul is "spawn" in indonesian. basically it spawn the tiles in random position and random rotation of the given image.

Comment: The question wasn't really what `Muncul` means translated (interesting though) but rather how and when it is getting called in your code .. since your title claims the issue is related with the spawn I guess it would be good to know how exactly this is happening ;)

Comment: `Muncul` is called when the editor record the song to detect the song beats. as the editor record, the tiles spawn corresponding to the song beats. but im guessing the problem is because of lag. instead of using `instantiate` i'll try using object pool. i'll let you know if that works